# Java - Seat Reservation System with buttons

Tags: java

I need to make an airline reservation system I have this set of buttons than when clicked will
be disabled and their value will be added to the database together with the other details of the passenger. My question is how can I make the buttons that are already reserved be disabled the next time i run my program.

i tried using this code

```
            resultset.next();
            String a = resultset.getString("Seat");
            s1.setText(a);
             resultset.next();
             String b = resultset.getString("Seat");
            s2.setText(b);
            resultset.next();
            String c = resultset.getString("Seat");
            s3.setText(c);
           resultset.next();
            String d = resultset.getString("Seat");
            s4.setText(d);
            resultset.next();
            String e = resultset.getString("Seat");
            s5.setText(e);
            resultset.next();
             String f = resultset.getString("Seat");
            s6.setText(f);
            resultset.next();
            String g = resultset.getString("Seat");
            s7.setText(g);
            resultset.next();
            String h = resultset.getString("Seat");
            s8.setText(h);

            if(zxc.contentEquals("Seat 1A")){
                    Seat1A.setEnabled(false);
                    Seat1A.setBackground(Color.red);
       }
                   else   if(zxc.contentEquals("Seat 2B")){
                    Seat2B.setEnabled(false);
                    Seat2B.setBackground(Color.red);
       }

                     else   if(zxc.contentEquals("Seat 3C")){
                    Seat3C.setEnabled(false);
                    Seat3C.setBackground(Color.red);
       }
                    else   if(zxc.contentEquals("Seat 4D")){
                    Seat4D.setEnabled(false);
                    Seat4D.setBackground(Color.red);
       }
                    else   if(zxc.contentEquals("Seat 5E")){
                    Seat5E.setEnabled(false);
                    Seat5E.setBackground(Color.red);
       }
```

and so on
    however this code is so long and when my resultset fetches a null value all the buttons that was already reserved will not be disabled.

Comment: you could use some array or list here

Comment: Using database would be a better option

Comment: Add a new column in table to indicate if booked/reserved already

Answer (score 0):

you could use `hashmap`

when you read from database

```
HashMap<String , JButton> myButtons = new HashMap<String , JButton>();

while(resultset.hasNext()){

     myButtons.push(resultset.getString("Seat") , yourButton);

}
```

and to make it disabled

```
for(String key : myButtons.keySet()){

   if(key.equals("Seat 1A")){
     JButton button = myButtons.get(key);
     button.setEnabled(false);
     button.setBackground(Color.red);
   }

}
```

for the `String` that you are using you could use a `List`

```
List seats = new ArrayList();
seats.add("Seat 1A");
...
```

then change your if statement

```
   if(seats.contains(key)){
     JButton button = myButtons.get(key);
     button.setEnabled(false);
     button.setBackground(Color.red);
   }
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! although i still have one problem left 
even those buttons that are not still reserved are disabled